# Notificações com SignalR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

Quero criar um sistema de notificações no meu web app (MVC) utilizando SignalR 2.

Quando alguém na app fizer uma determinada ação alguns usuários (não são todos e nem sempre são os mesmos) devem ser notificados. Algo parecido com o que temos aqui no SO quando alguém interage com uma pergunta.
Minha questão é a seguinte:

Qual seria uma melhor estratégia para enviar a mensagem para os clientes?

Devo armazenar em banco o connectionId e depois retornar este valor para quem deve ser notificado? Desta forma o banco de dados retornaria a lista de connectionId dos usuários que devem ser notificados após a ação.

Sou novo nisso e não sei como adaptar ao meu negócio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma interessante de mandar uma notificação para usuários específicos, é utilizando grupos. Para cada tipo de notificação, você cria grupos para cada *item* e conecte os clientes necessários a esses grupos. Um exemplo simples:

```
public class MeuHub : Hub
{
    public Task EntraNoGrupo(string grupoId)
    {
        return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, grupoId);
    }

    public Task SaiDoGrupo(string grupoId)
    {
        return Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, grupoId);
    }

    public void NotificaGrupo(string grupoId, string mensagem)
    {
        Clients.Group(grupoId).algumMetodoNosClientes(mensagem);
    }

}
```

Para você conectar um client a um grupo, basta invocar o método `EntraNoGrupo` do seu cliente, passando o Id desse grupo:

```
hubProxy.invoke('EntraNoGrupo', '453841'); // o Id do grupo
```

Ou seja, o método `EntraNoGrupo` é só uma forma do cliente conseguir entrar em um grupo, sendo que esse método deve ser chamado em todos os clientes daquele grupo.

> Para mais detalhes, leia na [documentação sobre Grupos do SignalR](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups).

---

Agora, sobre vincular uma `connectionId` a um usuário, existem algumas formas de você fazer isso, uma delas você inclusive já citou. Para decidir qual a mais adequada para o teu cenário, veja a tabela a seguir:

[image: Tabela - Formas para Persistir Id de Conexão]

Está em inglês mas acredito que dê para entender.

### Single-user Groups

Para o teu cenário em particular, a opção **Single-user Groups** já não é possível, pois ela sugere que você crie um grupo para cada usuário, no entanto isso retira a possibilidade de você notificar diferentes clientes em um mesmo grupo.

### Em Memória

Esse é mais para notificações triviais e até mesmo para quem está começando apenas ver como funciona. Ele atrapalha escalabilidade, pois por persistir tudo na memória do servidor, se você tiver um ambiente de farm, cada servidor tem sua própria memória, e daí podemos ter problemas. Pode ser que nem seja teu caso no momento, mas é interessante sempre construir as coisas pensando no futuro (sua aplicação pode crescer).

### UserID Provider

Esse aqui é parecido com o "em memória", no entanto esse suporta ambiente farm, pois faz uso de cookies no cliente, permitindo que diferentes servidores acessem esses cookies do cliente. No entanto, nesse aqui o servidor não mantém uma lista dos usuários conectados. Desde que você não precise mandar notificações para usuários específicos de um grupo, ou seja, as notificações serão sempre ao grupo inteiro (com a opção de excluir o próprio cliente que originou a chamada), estaria ok esse caso. O problema é que se o servidor reinicia ou ocorre um recycle na pool do IIS, o(s) servidor(es) perde(m) todas as configurações dos grupos.

### Persistência Externa

É exatamente o exemplo que você citou com banco de dados. Você persiste as informações de grupos e conexões em um banco de dados, e você não perde mais essas informações após um recycle na pool do IIS, nem quando o usuário limpar os cookies do browser, e suporta farm. O único lado negativo desse é que por ter que persistir em um banco de dados, fica um pouco mais lento para conectar e enviar mensagens, que também poderia ser resolvido com cache distribuído (em uma arquitetura mais sólida).

Mas eu nem pensaria em cache nesse primeiro momento. Banco de dados padrão, vai guardando os dados lá, fazendo testes. Se tu começar a ter um fluxo de notificações muito alta para aquele determinado Hub, daí tu começa a pensar em cache.

> Para ver mais sobre esses modelos de persistência de conexão x usuário, veja na [documentação do SignalR](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections).

Espero ter esclarecido tuas dúvidas, e que isso te ajude a decidir qual estratégia adotar para seu caso em particular.

Comment: Show sua resposta